# Jquery mapping images and loading them on different page

Tags: jquery, object

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gapx8gshb5ygbmp/Screenshot%202014-02-03%2009.30.09.png

I added a colorpicker, an iconpicker and the icon to this table as you can see.

The html of one icon looks like this:

```
    <tr id="tr_group530" class="row_b">
    <td style="with:auto;">
    <div class="iconennew" style=" background-color:#000000; background-size: 15px 15px"/>
    <img src="http://cdn.tribalwars.nl/8.18/19348/graphic/unit/unit_ram.png?2003e"   class="changetheicon" style="background-size: 15px 15px; background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0)"/>
    </td></tr>
```

What I want to do is store every icon per group (a group is 01. Off for example) (so the background color with class iconennew and the image with class changetheicon (or I could give the TD a class and do it like that, that's fine too) in LocalStorage to then add them to a different page.

To get the group name, I just have to use the following:

```
  $("#group_table").find('td[id*="show_group"]').each(function(){

$(this).text();
// Here I could get every image (td) as well


})
```

Now, my question is what would be the best way to store the html for every group name, and then add the correct image before every group on this page:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yj9wpul2hrxtw57/Screenshot%202014-02-03%2009.39.54.png

With html:

```
  <div id="paged_view_content">
 <div class="vis_item" align="center">
 <a href="/game.php?village=11180&mode=combined&group=530&screen=overview_villages"    class="group_tooltip">[01. Off]</a>
 <a href="/game.php?village=11180&mode=combined&group=3681&screen=overview_villages" class="group_tooltip">[02. Sp/Zc_F]</a>
  <a href="/game.php?village=11180&mode=combined&group=3683&screen=overview_villages" class="group_tooltip">[03. Sp/ZC_S]</a>
  </div></div>
```

If something isn't clear or you'd rather have the html in a fiddle, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use `$(this).contents()` instead of `$(this).text()`

Comment: No, text works fine and I need the group name to check it against the group names on the other page. But I need to map (or something like that) every td for every group name and then add that td to a different page for the corresponding group.